# Constructing simple function in R with names() and lapply() to a list

Tags: r, list, function, loops, lapply

I am trying to switch my thinking more into applying lapply or functions instead of continuously looping. Here I have a code which works nicely in a loop - the goal is simple: giving names to each column in each element of the list. I would like to convert it to a function instead but I can't make it work.

```
data1 <- data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
data2 <- data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
data3 <- data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10))

data <- list(data1,data2,data3)



for (i in 1:length(data)) {
        names(data[[i]]) <- c("x", "y", "r")
}
```

Here is where I am getting it wrong:

```
lapply(data, function(x) names(x) <-  c("x", "y", "f"))
```

And this function doesn't work for me neither:

```
givenames <- function (x) {
        names(x) <-  c("x", "y", "f")
}

lapply(data,givenames)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good initiative!

In your function you were almost there. In fact you are not returning the `data.frame`, you should do:

```
lapply(data, function(x) {names(x) <-  c("x", "y", "f"); x})
```

Which is the same as:

```
lapply(data, function(x) {
    names(x) <-  c("x", "y", "f")
    x
})
```

Here is a concise solution:

```
lapply(data, setNames, c('x','y','f'))
```

Note that `setNames` returns the a `data.frame`, reason why it works.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you what is the additional `x` after the semicolon needed in the `{names(x) <-  c("x", "y", "f"); x}` piece of code?

Comment: Also `lapply(data, function(x) "names<-"(x,c("x", "y", "f")))` works. @Anna in R you can write two commands on the same line as long as you put a `;` between them.

Comment: you can define several instructions on one line by separating them with `;`, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel: Thanks so much! But I still don't get why do we need to type single x after the expression assigning names - what is the purpose? I know it is an ignorant question but it will help me understand it.

Comment: @Anna your function takes a dataframe, modify names and returns a dataframe. So you can mention return(x) but beware that in R, the last element in a function is returned. So we can just write x. I strongly advice you to read this: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#return-values

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: Fantastic reference, exactly what I need now to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @nicola - i think there are accidental apostrophes in your code though and when i run `lapply(data, function(x) names<-(x,c("x", "y", "f")))` it doesnt work

Comment: no it was `lapply(data, function(x) \`names<-\`(x,c("x", "y", "f")))`